# Neo4J - unable to create relationships (30,000)

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

I've got two csv files `Job` (30,000 entries) and `Cat` (30 entries) imported into neo4j and am trying to create a relationship between them
Each Job has a `cat_ID` and `Cat` contains the category name and ID
after executing the following

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///DimCategory.csv' AS row
MATCH (job:Job {cat_ID: row.cat_ID})
MATCH (cat:category {category: row.category})
CREATE (job)-[r:under]->(cat)
```

it returns (no changes, no records)

I received a prompt recommending that I index the category and so using
 `Create INDEX ON :Job(cat_id);` I did, but I still get the same error

How do I create a relationship between the two?
I am able to get this to work on a smaller dataset

Answer (score 0):

You are probably trying to match on non-existing nodes. Try

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///DimCategory.csv' AS row
MERGE (job:Job {cat_ID: row.cat_ID})
MERGE (cat:category {category: row.category})
CREATE (job)-[r:under]->(cat)
```

Comment: Unfortunately it gives an error that I have null values despite all rows being filled in the CSV
I have attempted to remedy it using 
```WITH row WHERE row.cat_ID IS NOT NULL```
which returns no changes once more

Answer (score 0):

Have a look in your logs and see if you are running out of memory.

You could try chunking the data set up into smaller pieces with Periodic Commit and see if that helps:

```
:auto USING PERIODIC COMMIT 1000
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///DimCategory.csv' AS row
MATCH (job:Job {cat_ID: row.cat_ID})
MATCH (cat:category {category: row.category})
CREATE (job)-[r:under]->(cat)
```